# Inno Setup Shortcut Issue

Tags: inno-setup

I have one small, but frustrating issue.
I create installer with possibility for shortcut for the executable, but if the executable is not in the main folder in lets say MyProgram\bin\myprogram.exe the installer makes copy of the .exe in the main program folder and shortcut path is not MyProgram\bin\myprogram.exe like it supposed to be, but its MyProgram\myprogram.exe and of course it won't run until i make manual shortcut from bin folder. 
Hope you guys understand my problem and tell me where i can fix this in the script.

Comment: The fix to your script would depend on where the error is in your script. I'd guess you have the [Icon] entry wrong. It should be, e.g., `Name:"{group}\MyProgram";Filename:"{app}\bin\myprogram.exe"`

Comment: @Sertac, I'd say you can make this an answer (as I was going to). But strange would be that InnoSetup would copy the binary to the location specified by `[Icons]` entry. That part with *the installer makes copy of the .exe* sounds really strange.

Comment: Sertac helped me now it works as is should be. Thanks a lot

Comment: Accepted it. It still copies executable into main game folder, but now shortcut path is correct and its running without creating my own. I don't mind this executable now, because i can just delete it.

Comment: It must be a consequence of something else. Look carefully in your `[Files]` section.

Comment: @user1695272: Welcome to StackOverflow. In future, please post as much information as you can that will allow someone to answer. In this case, the code in question would be invaluable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an error with your [Icon] entry, try something like:

```
Name:"{group}\MyProgram";Filename:"{app}\bin\myprogram.exe
```