# Inno Setup: How do I change the text used for the shortcut it makes?

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut

I have a main application, *MainProgram.exe* and another application, *Launcher.exe* that simply does a little bit of work, launches the main application (*MainProgram.exe*) and shuts itself down. I don't want my users to know that the launcher is being run.

Using Inno setup I can install both programs into a folder, make a short cut to *Launcher.exe* and even start *Launcher.exe* when setup finishes.

But how do I tell Inno setup to set the **text** of the shortcut or menu item that the user sees to be **MainProgram.exe** and not **Launcher.exe**, even though the file actually being pointed to is Launcher.exe 
(same for the text of the 'Uninstall ...' menu item).

I did check both of these SO questions but neither gave the answer.

[Renaming/replacing ShortCut During Inno Setup Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336082/renaming-replacing-shortcut-during-inno-setup-installation)

[Inno Setup Shortcut Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570719/inno-setup-shortcut-issue)

I guess I could just swap the filenames round but thay would be just too confusing!

Comment: @KenWhite Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks Ken. That seemed to work. As Martin says, if you can post this as an answer I can accept it and you get the credit (before sombody else does!)

Comment: Done. Didn't have a way to double-check first before posting an answer (the above is from memory). Thanks for confirming it worked. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this up using the [Icons] section in your install script. An example would be:

```
Name: "{group}\Main Program"; FileName: "{app}\Launcher.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; IconFIleName: "{app}\MainProgram.exe"; Comment: "This is your launcher program in disguise".
```